# Maximal unramified quotient of $E[p]$ for the action of $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ with good and ordinary reduction at an odd prime $p$.
Suppose $E[p]$ denotes the $p$-torsion points of $E$ and $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p} := \text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}/\mathbb{Q}_p)$.

In the article `Selmer group and congruences (page 6)', Greenberg says that one can characterize $\widetilde{E}[p]$ as the maximal unramified quotient of $E[p]$ for the action of $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ where $\widetilde{E}$ denotes the reduction of $E$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

This is so because $p$ is assumed to be odd and therefore the action of the inertia subgroup of $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ on the kernel of the reduction map $\pi: E[p] \longrightarrow \widetilde{E}[p]$ is nontrivial.

It will be every helpful if someone can explain how `$p$ being odd' is playing a role in proving the non trivial action of the inertia subgroup on the kernel of the reduction map $\pi$ ?

Comment: For p=2 you could have all 2-torsion points defined over $\mathbb{Q}_2$ and so all of $E[2]$ is umramified. For $p>2$, the formal group  can't have $p$-torsion points defined over that base field, you would have to make a ramified extension to get them.